Raspberry Pi 4 で特定のWi-Fiのときだけwebページが開かない
Raspberry Pi 4 Model Bでｗebページが開かず、お手上げなので相談させてください。
職場に社内Lan用Wi-FiとフリーWi-Fiがあり、社内Lan用Wi-Fiにつないだときだけ、webページが開きません。Pingは通ります。また同一Wi-Fiにつないでいるパソコンからはwebページは開きます。
状況をまとめますと下記のような状況です
社内Lan用Wi-Fi接続時
Raspberry Pi
Webページ　開かない
www.yahoo.co.jpへのping　とおる
パソコンからのVNC接続　できる
パソコン
Webページ　開く
www.yahoo.co.jpへのping　とおる
フリーWi-Fi接続時
Raspberry Pi
Webページ　開く
www.yahoo.co.jpへのping　とおる
パソコンからのVNC接続　できない
パソコン
Webページ　開く
www.yahoo.co.jpへのping　とおる
セットアップを行ったばかりなので、firewall等は設定していません。
何か他に確認した方が良いことや、設定をした方が良いことがありますでしょうか？

まずは社内のネットワーク管理者に問い合わせることを優先すべきです。わざわざフリー Wi-Fi に分けられてるという事は、社内 LAN の方にはセキュリティ確保のために制限がかかっている可能性があります。 (MAC アドレスのフィルタリング、プロキシが必要等) この辺りの詳しい情報は第三者には分かりません。

確認遅くなりました。
もちろんネットワーク管理者には確認済みです。
ネットワーク的には問題ないので、rasberryPI側の問題ではないかと言われました。
